# MacBook Pro Boot loop

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup

Since this morning my 2018 MacBook Pro has been stuck in a boot loop. When I start it up, I hear the chime (sometimes I see the apple logo) and this repeats.

SMC and NVRAM reset didnt help. I can't start my MacBook in Verbose mode and can't start the Apple hardware test. I can start my system in Recovery mode but as soon as it finished downloading it will get stuck in the loop again. I also tried to boot macOS from a stick but as soon as I select the stick as boot device, it gets stuck in the loop again.

I dont know what to do now. Does anyone haven any ideas how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

it looks like a hardware issue, i would take it to Support. i experienced something similar once, and the problem was my Charger, i bought one that was not original and the beginning worked, but after sometime it was causing problems, i happened to have an original one close to me, i tested it and it worked.

Comment: I agree with @Yohanmaker. If you can't boot all the way, it is a hardware issue.